# PHP - mod_rewrite clean urls and query strings

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s/%1 ^(on(s)|offs)/(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3%{REQUEST_URI}/site1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/site1/catalogue/(\w+)/([0-9]+)$ catalogue.php?category=$1&product_id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

I'm having trouble with some mod_rewrites. I'm trying to accomplish 3 things:

1) Remove www. from urls

2) Remove the .php extensions

3) Have clean urls involving $_GET variables (query strings?)

For example, I would like this url:

http://www.domain.com/site1/catalogue.php?category=kitchen&product_id=2

turned into this:

http://www.domain.com/site1/catalogue/kitchen/2

Comment: So what's the trouble? And where is this htaccess file? In the `site1` directory or your document root?

Comment: in which thing are you facing issue

Comment: @Jon Lin - Sorry, for not being specific enough. Yes, my .htaccess file is inside the site1 folder/directory. Entering the cleaned url doesn't seem to be redirecting me properly. I'm getting 404s. I'm assuming the problem is my last rewrite rule for the query string.

Comment: Run `phpinfo();` in a file and make sure the mod_rewrite.so extension is enabled.

Comment: @cillosis - Yes, I did run phpinfo() beforehand and the mod_rewrite module is enabled. So I'm kinda baffled as to what's going on. :p I have asked my web hosting provider if they have mod_rewrite enabled as well and they have assured me it is.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, my .htaccess file is inside the site1 folder/directory. Entering the cleaned url doesn't seem to be redirecting me properly. I'm getting 404s. I'm assuming the problem is my last rewrite rule for the query string.

Change the last rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^catalogue/(\w+)/([0-9]+)$ catalogue.php?category=$1&product_id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Removing the `/site1/` from the regular expression match. Also add this just after the `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteBase /site1/
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and unfortunately I'm still getting 404s when entering the cleaned url in my browser. It still doesn't seem to be redirecting for whatever reason.

Comment: @user1307016 are you sure it doesn't have anything to do with the stray `/site1` at the end of your redirect in your first rule? `http%2://%3%{REQUEST_URI}/site1`

Comment: I have removed /site1 from my first redirect rule and I'm still getting 404s with my cleaned url. I just tried a simple rewrite with my index page so it would bring me to http://www.domain.com/site1/home using RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [L] and that rule seems to be working. So I'm sure my mod_rewrite is enabled.